# Crypto key and client side signing for google maps api

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have got the crypto key and client id from google to sign my website. 
The google documentation says we should sign using server side generating the url using hash algorithm.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/get-api-key?utm_campaign=eps&utm_source=unify#sample-code-for-url-signing

But I have my map built in client side code using gmap with a reference to the script library. 
.." src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false">...

Can I include the crypto key directly in this tag as 
.script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=CRYPTO-KEY&sensor=false">..

Will this work fine or should I modify the code to get the urls server signed and build the map?

Help/Advice requested. Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like you should have support from Google, they should be able to help (if the documentation doesn't).

Answer (score 1):

You must not include crypto key in the <script> tag of Maps JavaScript API. You have to use the client parameter instead of key and additionally authorize the URL of your page in your support portal.

Your script tag should be like

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?client=CLIENT-ID&v=3></script>
```

Have a look at the documentation 
https://developers.google.com/maps/premium/previous-licenses/clientside/auth

Please note that crypto key is used to generate digital signatures of Web Service requests.